# Not getting background color in aws ses email template for a table cell based on value

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, amazon-ses

```
{
 "Template": {
"TemplateName": "sesHtmlTemplate",
"SubjectPart": "Export Status",
"HtmlPart": "<h3>Hello,</h3><style>h3{color:#e327ac;}</style><p>This is the table about latest job 
 execution details.</p><p style=margin-left:10%;></style><style>{% if value == 1 %} td {background- 
 color: green;} {% if value == 0 %} td {background-color: red}</style><table border=1 style=border- 
 collapse:collapse><tr><th bgcolor=#8e95f0>JOB_ID</th><th bgcolor=#8e95f0>JOB_RUNDATETIME</th><th 
 bgcolor=#8e95f0>DATA_DATE_START</th><th bgcolor=#8e95f0>LOADTYPE</th><th 
 bgcolor=#8e95f0>PROCESS_NAME</th><th bgcolor=#8e95f0>PROCESS_OUTPUT</th><th 
 bgcolor=#8e95f0>PROCESS_STATUS</th><th bgcolor=#8e95f0>ERROR_OUTPUT</th></tr><tr><td>782</td> 
 <td>2020-06-08 02:30:15.0</td><td>20200608</td><td>20200608</td><td>Scheduled</td><td>Data File 
 Availability Check - Files Are Available. Start the Scheduled Data Load</td><td {value=1 
 bgcolor=green} {value=0 bgcolor=red}>1</td><td>null</td></tr><tr><td>782</td><td>2020-06-08 
 02:30:15.0</td><td>20200608</td><td>20200608</td><td>Scheduled</td><td>Data File Availability Check 
 - Files Are Available. Start the Scheduled Data Load</td><td {value=1 bgcolor=green} {value=0 
 bgcolor=red}>0</td><td>null</td></tr></table></p><p>Please reach out to me if u have any queries 
 regarding this mail</p><p><strong>Thanks and Regards,</strong><br>xyz</p>"
 }
 }
```

Our requirement is to get green color for table cell if the value is 1 and red if the value is 0.Some code snippets including ajax are working fine in the windows environment.but when that html part is added to the aws ses template html under HtmlPart it is not working as expected.Need help in resolving this issue.

Comment: did you find any solution for this